# How to increase and decrease the product's quantity based on the "increment" value from the b2b catalog in Shopify Plus?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am searching for a way to force the product's quantity field to increase and decrease based on the minimum and increment for that product as set in its containing B2B catalog. For example, I have a product that is sold in increments of 6, and whose minimum is 6. When I click "plus" in the quantity box, I want it to increase to 12, 18, 24, etc. Likewise, when I click minus, it should then decrease from 24 to 18, 12, and back down to 6. It should also start at 6, not 1, since 6 is the minimum for that product. It should not be able to decrease to 0.

Some products may be 6, others may be 4, 12, etc. Therefore, I must use a dynamic field for the data.

This increment code works, but the decrement code decrements it all the way back down to the minimum value, instead of decreasing it by the increment value. If I can fix the decrement error, I think I will be good to go. Any ideas?

```
{% comment %}Increment code{% endcomment %}
    {% if customer.b2b? %}
      <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
          var quantityInput = document.querySelector('quantity-input input[name="quantity"]');
          
          {% assign minimumQuantity = product.variants.first.quantity_rule.min | default: 1 %}
          {% assign incrementQuantity = product.variants.first.quantity_rule.increment | default: 1 %}
          
          if (quantityInput) {
            // Ensure the initial value is set correctly
            quantityInput.value = "{{ minimumQuantity }}";
    
            // Update quantity on input change
            quantityInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
              var currentQuantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
              
              // Check if the entered quantity is less than the minimum
              if (currentQuantity < {{ minimumQuantity }}) {
                quantityInput.value = "{{ minimumQuantity }}";
              }
            });
    
            // Allow incrementing based on the product's "Increment" field
            var incrementButton = document.querySelector('quantity-input-plus');
            if (incrementButton) {
              incrementButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                // Introduce a small delay to avoid the initial increment by 1
                setTimeout(function () {
                  var currentQuantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
    
                  // Skip the first increment by 1
                  if (currentQuantity !== parseInt("{{ minimumQuantity }}")) {
                    var remainder = currentQuantity % parseInt("{{ incrementQuantity }}");
                    var nextQuantity = remainder === 0 ? currentQuantity : currentQuantity - remainder + parseInt("{{ incrementQuantity }}");
    
                    quantityInput.value = nextQuantity;
                  }
                }, 10);
              });
            }
          }
        });
      </script>
    {% endif %}


{% comment %}Decrement code{% endcomment %}
    {% if customer.b2b? %}
      <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
          var quantityInput = document.querySelector('quantity-input input[name="quantity"]');
          var decrementButton = document.querySelector('quantity-input-minus');
    
          {% assign minimumQuantity = product.variants.first.quantity_rule.min | default: 1 %}
          {% assign incrementQuantity = product.variants.first.quantity_rule.increment | default: 1 %}
    
          if (quantityInput && decrementButton) {
            // Ensure the initial value is set correctly
            quantityInput.value = "{{ minimumQuantity }}";
    
            decrementButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
              var currentQuantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
              var decrementAmount = parseInt("{{ incrementQuantity }}");
              var nextQuantity = Math.max(currentQuantity - decrementAmount, {{ minimumQuantity }});
    
              quantityInput.value = nextQuantity;
            });
          }
        });
      </script>
    {% endif %}
```